# C - definite integral Quadrature rule

Tags: c

I would apprecite a little help. I need to create simple application counting definite integral in quadrature rule, which is given as a parameter when running. I started with adding parametres, but when I use brackets in it, compiler won't compile my application. And then I am stuck in getting started, how to trasnfer parameter as a integral to some computing part?

Thanks

edit:

```
int x;
int i;
float sum=0;
double PI;

printf("Please enter the parts to divide the interval: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

for (i=1; i<x; i+=2){
    if (i%4==1)
        sum=sum+1./(double)i;
    else
        sum=sum-1./(double)i;
}
PI= 4*sum;
printf("The sum is %f\n", sum);
printf("Approximate value of PI is %f\n", PI);
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Edited, I need to find out how to approximate integral for certain input

Comment: try using `(float)` instead of `(double)`. Or declare `sum` as `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're asking here.

Are you trying to do Gaussian or some other type of quadrature scheme with differing orders?

Are you having problems figuring out how to pass a function pointer to be evaluated by the numerical integration function?

When you say you have a compiler error, it suggests that you haven't even gotten to the point where you can tell whether your implementation works or not.  How well do you know C?  You should read and digest the error message and go back to a language reference to see where you went wrong until all the compiler errors are gone.

Once you achieve that, the fun begins: now you have to worrk about whether or not your code actually works.

UPDATE: I don't see any quadrature in the code you posted.  Looks like a simple Euler or Simpson's rule.

I'd recommend something like "Numerical Recipes":

http://eiffel.ps.uci.edu/cyu/p231C/LectureNotes/lecture10:integration/lecture10.pdf

Comment: I put here my simple code, I am asking for help in case of how to generalize app in C, that this app will approximate given function from parameter and dependently on how many intervals I choose, it will have some kind of accuracy. I seek for some general code how to approximate integrals in general, because for my is up to now big obstruction. Like for PI, I will get better and better results limitting to 3,14159265...

Comment: Read that reference I posted.  It can be done, but not as written by you.

Comment: THank you for the link, its shame that there is no quadrature (or rectangular) method, i know its not the best... but I will look further.

Comment: I think it's easy to write.  That's that the link will help you with.